# Get all classes from namespace and work on their properties

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-5.0

I want to get all classes from namespace so I have used this code:

```
var theList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                  .Where(t => t.Namespace == myNameSpace)
                  .ToList();
```

It's working but when I'm looping through this list, I want to create instance or call constructor of each class in theList list and for example call their methods or properties.

Ofc this code is not working, but this is my purpose.

```
foreach (Type t in theList)
        {
            description += t.Description;
        }
```

@Edit
I did:

```
        var theList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
              .Where(t => t.Namespace == myNameSpace)
              .ToList();

        foreach (Type t in theList)
        {
            Command instance = (Command)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            result += Environment.NewLine + instance.Name + " - " + instance.Description;
        }
```

Comment: I don't know how concatenating descriptions (I don't think this is a member in the first place) corresponds to "create instances and call methods". Can you clarify?

Comment: look into `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: Description is just string property. I added this for example. I mean I want to work with class properties and methods that are in theLlist list.

Comment: You need to look into 'reflection' and everything that comes with it. It allows you to create objects and call methods/properties at runtime.

Comment: @Porqqq Is `Description` a static property?  If you create a new instance will `Description` be set to a default value or will it be `null`?

Comment: @DStanley Its gonna be default

Comment: @Porqqq So a value other than `null`?

Comment: @DStanley Yeah. I think i would use that Activator.CreateInstance(). But if u have other options..

Answer (score 0):

To create an instance of a class you can call `Activator.CreateInstance()`.

Thereis also a nice extension method that I use to get properties and values from objects:

```
/// <summary>
///     Gets all public properties of an object and and puts them into dictionary.
/// </summary>
public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    // if an object is dynamic it will convert to IDictionary<string, object>
    var result = instance as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (result != null)
        return result;

    return instance.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(instance));
}
```